# Need help explaining ajax post error

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection

```
private readonly UserService userService;

    public AccountController(UserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        bool validUser = this.userService.ValidateUser(username, password);
       // bool validUser = UserService.ValidateUser(username, password);
        if (validUser)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, true);
            return Json(new
                {
                    valid = true,
                    action = "Views/Home/Index"
                });
        }
        else
        {
            return Json(new
                {
                    valid = false,
                    action = "Views/Account/_LoginPartial"
                });
        }
    }
```

My ajax post can't reach the method `Login` because of the:

```
 private readonly UserService userService;

    public AccountController(UserService userService)
    {
        this.userService = userService;
    }
```

If I delete this code it works. But why?
How can I use `userService` in my Login-method without instantiating it like that?

Answer (score 1):

> My ajax post can't reach the method Login because of the:

```
private readonly UserService userService;

public AccountController(UserService userService)
{
    this.userService = userService;
}
```

Of course! You probably miss and need a *factory* to create this `Controller` for you with the desired `UserService` (I wonder why not using `interface`), otherwise, this `Controller` will not be instantiated and thus the `Login` Action would **not** be invoked.

This is a [DI Construction Injection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921152.aspx) which should automatically occur for you if you have a well-configured Controller Factory in your application.

**Here is a simple custom Controller Factory that you can use:**

```
public class CustomControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        UserService userService = new UserService();
        IController controller = Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, new[] { userService }) as Controller;
        return controller;
    }
}
```

**And don't forget to register it:**

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
      RegisterCustomControllerFactory ();
    }

    private void RegisterCustomControllerFactory ()
    {
      IControllerFactory factory = new CustomControllerFactory();
      ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(factory);
   }
}
```

Read this article: [ASP.NET MVC Controller Dependency Injection for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/560798/ASP-NET-MVC-Controller-Dependency-Injection-for-Be)

Answer (score 1):

this controller looks like its intended to work with a dependency injection tool.

If you have one in place, then you're dependency resolver is probably not configured correctly.  If you don't have one in place then there are various ones like ninject, unity, simple injector, etc. that can be installed using nuget.